# How to convert byte[] or bitmap to integer (R.drawable.picture) Android java

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to convert

```
byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(5);

Bitmap bit_image = getImage(image);
```

Either `byte[]` or `Bitmap` into an `R.drawable.picture`.

I need it to be an `integer` (`int` and not `int[]`) because my custom list view only accepts and `int`.

```
list_view_class.add(new List_view_class(R.drawable.picture,text);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do what you are trying to do. 
`R.drawable` or `R.string` and so on **are not the resources itself**, but an **reference to the resources in the application**. So you can't convert anysort of object to `R` or something. What you can do is use the `Bitmap` and display it directly.